# Angular material 9 broken UI

Tags: angular9, angular-material-9

I am getting the following warning message

- Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of
  'mat-table'.
- Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
- Can't bind to 'breadcrumbs' since it isn't a known
  property of 'app-bread-crumb'.
- Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
- Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-error'.

All these warning point to components under a single module named "import-export".
I have imported all the angular material into a single module named "angular-material" and have imported angular-material into import-export module

How to resolve all these issues?

Answer (score 0):

The warning messages were purely because of incorrect import. I corrected the imports in the correct module and there are no more warning or error messages.